@RestClientTest with RestClient (NOT RestTemplate)
I understand the @TestRestClient helps us easily test classes that use RestTemplate to call REST services.  I have several classes which use Spring's RestClient (NOT RestTemplate, NOT WebClient) to make REST calls.  Can I test such classes with the @TestRestClient or do I need to use something like WireMock?  My web searches have drawn a blank.
If not, is such support planned for a future release of Spring Boot?

I know that my answer comes a little too late but maybe will help for future reference. According to documentation, we can use the @RestClientTest annotation to test REST clients. Also from here, we can see that there's a bindTo method that accepts RestClient.Builder. This method is available since version 6.1.
With that in mind, let's suppose we have the next client class to test:
@Component
public class HelloClient {

    private final RestClient restClient;

    public HelloClient(RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder) {
        this.restClient = restClientBuilder.baseUrl("https://www.hello.com")
                .build();
    }

    public String fetchResponse() {
        return restClient.get()
                .uri("/world")
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
    }
}

A test using the @RestClientTest should look like this:
@RestClientTest(HelloClient.class)
public class HelloClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private HelloClient helloClient;

    @Autowired
    private RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restClientBuilder).build();
    }

    @Test
    void fetchResponse() {
        // given: a valid response
        String response = "Hello World";

        // and: configure the client to return that response
        mockServer.expect(requestTo("https://www.hello.com/world"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(response, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        // when: calling the client
        String clientResponse = helloClient.fetchResponse();

        // then: the response gets returned
        assertEquals("Hello World", clientResponse);
    }
}



Since Spring says to start a (true) mock web server for WebClient, I would assume the same recommendation goes for RestClient. That also makes you independent from the actual client implementation. See their own test of RestClient in the Spring repo.
The Spring test starts up a server that actually listens to a port and returns HTTP replies you tell it to use. It is using OkHttp as the mock server, but you could use any other mock server.

This works for me:
@RestClientTest(FooClient::class)
class FooClientTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var fooClient: FooClient

    @Autowired
    lateinit var server: MockRestServiceServer

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        // mock here server
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldTest() {
        fooClient.bar()
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    class Conf {
        @Bean
        fun restClient(restClientBuilder: RestClient.Builder) = restClientBuilder.build()
    }
}

